# Fulltext search in a CTE result - missing fulltext index

Tags: mariadb, full-text-search, cte, mariadb-10.2

My question applies to MariaDB 10.2.7

The query

```
WITH prefiltered AS (
  SELECT id, fulltext_indexed_column
  FROM fulltext_table
  WHERE id < 30
)
SELECT *
FROM prefiltered
WHERE MATCH(fulltext_indexed_column) AGAINST ('Foo')
```

leads to

```
Error #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I understand why, the CTE results are not indexed. I can rewrite the query to not use the CTE, or to use fulltext search inside the first CTE.

But is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do in this? Tell the DB to index the CTE results?

Comment: Looks like a query optimizer bug to me -- it should be able to perform the CTE merge (unless your actual query is different).

Comment: The query is exactly the same, except for different table and column names.